# Why the series of one state variable is getting other state variable value in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, state, react-highcharts

Here, I have two state charts: Chart One and Chart Two. On the first click of the Chart One button, it renders the charts correctly. However, when I try to click on Chart Two, it doesn't work. Instead, the Chart Two series receives values from Chart One. How can I avoid this issue?

Thank you.

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-microservice-f0clmh?file=/src/Example.tsx

If I use a direct constant variable instead of state, the error disappears. However, I need to use state. Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Hi @pradeep upadhya, You've probably updated the live example and now it is not showing the issue. However, the problem seems to be related to Highcharts data mutations, which are made because of performance reasons. You can change this behaviour through: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.allowMutatingData

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the unique key of the HighchartsReact.

```
<HighchartsReact highcharts={ Highcharts } options={ chartOne } key="chartOne"/> :
<HighchartsReact highcharts={ Highcharts } options={ chartTwo } key="chartTwo"/>
```

I added the key and gave it a retry and it worked.

https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-breeze-sufxo1

Comment: Hi @Ashu, This is not an optimal solution. In this case, the whole chart would be recreated and we only need to update it.

Comment: `immutable={true}` work even.